# Writing an advanced regular expression

Tags: javascript, php, node.js

Firstly sorry for my bad English. I'm newbie with regex. I'm trying to make auto translation. For example I have a text like:

```
/begin CHARACTERISTIC

    AccPed_trqEngLow_MAP
    "Kennfeld für AWD"
    MAP
    0x801B425C
    Map_Xs16Ys16Ws16
    1500.000
    Trq
    -500.0000
    1000.000

    FORMAT "%8.3"
    EXTENDED_LIMITS -3276.800 3276.700


    /begin AXIS_DESCR

        STD_AXIS
        Epm_nEng
        EngN
        16
        0.00
        10000.00

        FORMAT "%8.2"
        EXTENDED_LIMITS -16384.00 16383.50
        DEPOSIT ABSOLUTE

    /end AXIS_DESCR

    /begin AXIS_DESCR

        STD_AXIS
        AccPed_rAPP
        Prc
        8
        0.00
        100.0000

        FORMAT "%8.4"
        EXTENDED_LIMITS -400.0000 399.9878
        DEPOSIT ABSOLUTE

    /end AXIS_DESCR

/end CHARACTERISTIC
```

I need to select all strings in `""` like `"Kennfeld für AWD"`, but do not select where starts with `%` (`"%8.3"`) Is it possible at least? Thanks in advance.. P.S string may contain quotation marks inside, like `"Hello "world" !"` It is very difficult for me.

Comment: You could use PCRE verbs if this is being run in PHP.

Comment: @user3783243 actually that leads to a good question - where is this going to be run? It could influence the regex implementation.

Comment: @vlaz I think probably I'll translate regex with PHP

Comment: Maybe https://regex101.com/r/rsx2QU/2/ works for you?

Comment: @user3783243 Thank you so much! One problem left. It is quotation marks inside like `"Hello "world" !"`

Comment: Encapsulation marks should be unique, or escaped. Whatever is building your string should be modified.

Comment: @user3783243 I have tried with node. Why I get `\"%\d+\.\d+"(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|"[^"]+"/: Nothing to repeat` ? :(

Comment: That sounds like a JS error. That regex was for PHP which uses PCRE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/\"([^%].*)\"/g` matches all strings in quotes that don't start with a % symbol.

In javascript (es6) it would be:

```
const example = `
/begin CHARACTERISTIC

    AccPed_trqEngLow_MAP
    "Kennfeld für AWD"
    MAP
    0x801B425C
    Map_Xs16Ys16Ws16
    1500.000
    Trq
    -500.0000
    1000.000

    FORMAT "%8.3"
    EXTENDED_LIMITS -3276.800 3276.700

/end CHARACTERISTIC
`

let re =  /\"([^%].*)\"/g;
let results = example.match(re);

console.log(results)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about?

```
<?php
$string = '
WHATVER "Kennfeld für AWD"
FORMAT "%8.3"
"Hello "World" !"
FOO
BAR
FORMAT "%8.2"
FORMAT "%8.4"
/end CHARACTERISTIC';

preg_match_all('/"((?!\%).+)"/', $string, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($matches);
echo "</pre>";
```